# Storing Lines into a dynamic struct

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, stdin

I'm writing a function that stores lines from stdin and dynamically allocates memory for it in a structure. When I compile my code, I get 3 errors and I don't get why I get these errors.

The errors are as follows:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `strcpy'
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `free'
```

Here is the function:

```
#define NAMESIZE 20
#define BLOCK 2
typedef struct
{
char last[NAMESIZE];
char first[NAMESIZE];
}name;

typedef struct
{
int id;
name name;
float score;
}record;

typedef struct
{
record *data;
size_t nalloc;
size_t nused;
}record_list;


int list_insert(record_list *list, const record *rec)
{
char * temp;
char lines[512];
size_t i;
list->nalloc = 0;
list->nused = 0;

while(fgets(lines, 512, stdin))
{
    if(list->nalloc == list->nused)
    {
        temp = realloc(list->data, (list->nalloc + BLOCK) * sizeof(char *));

        if(temp == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resize memory\n");
            break;
        }

        list->data = (record *)temp;
        list->nalloc += BLOCK;
    }
    list->data[list->nused] = malloc(strlen(lines) + 1); /*problem line*/
    strcpy(list->data[list->nused++], lines);/*problem line*/

}
for(i = 0; i < list->nused; i++)
{
    free(list->data[i]); /*problem line*/
}
free(list->data);


return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appeciated.

Answer (score 1):

`list->data` is a pointer to `record`, so `list->data[i]` is of type `record`. All your problem lines expect a `char *` or at least some kind of pointer, which results in the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be using `list->data[i]` as a pointer, but since `list->data` is a `record*` then `list->data[i]` is a `record`, not a `record*`.

With your current data structures, only one malloc/free pair is needed ; everything except `list->data` has a known and constant length.

Now your realloc is really wrong, you need to allocate a multiple of `sizeof (*list->data)` (i.e. `sizeof (record)`). Your code will also fail if the first call to realloc returns null (you're breaking out of the loop and try to free `list->data` which may be null here).

Answer (score 1):

```
list->data[list->nused] = malloc(strlen(lines) + 1);
```

`list->data` has type `record *`, but you address it (with `[list-nused]`), so that the type of `list->data[list->nused]` is `record`, and you assign a pointer to it. For this to work, the `data` structure member in `record_list` would have to have be a pointer to pointer.

Also, you want to allocate memory for the string (since you allocate `strlen(lines) + 1` bytes). But you don't have any variable to store a string: `record` has an int, a float and two character arrays, which have fixed size.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char *name;
    float score;
} record;

...
temp = realloc(list->data, list->nalloc * sizeof(record));
...
list->data[list->nused].name = malloc(strlen(lines) + 1);
strcpy(list->data[list->nused++].name, lines);
...
free(list->data[i].name);
```

So you allocate the record (int, char pointer, float), and where the char pointer is, you allocate memory for the string.

Comment: Can't really change the structure. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you use the current structure, you don't need to dynamically allocate memory for the strings, you already have the buffers (last and first). Then you just do a realloc(), no malloc(), and copy the string to &list->data[list->nused++].last.